# When multiple networks in Docker compose ports aren't being mapped

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two compose files, first one is for postgres services and the second one for a web service, then I have two docker networks for each one, I want connect web services to postgres services, so I assign two networks at web service compose file, also I need port mapping for web service, but docker only make the mapping when I assign one network, when I assign two networks to the web service mapping no works, How I can solve this? (I must not use Docker Links)

I have the next compose file for web service:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
      networks:
      - postgres_network
      - web_network

networks:
  web_network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.90.91.0/24
        gateway: 172.90.91.1
  postgres_network:
    external:
      name: postgres_postgres_network
```

Previously I have created postgres service and postgres_postgres_network network

Reference: [Specifying custom networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Thanks so much